# Why TS doen't allow run function?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webdriver-io

https://www.npmjs.com/package/wdio-intercept-service

I was copy code from example (Usage with WebDriver Standalone):

```
import WebdriverAjax from 'wdio-intercept-service';
const interceptServiceLauncher = WebdriverAjax();
```

But TS throw error:

```
Cannot use namespace 'WebdriverAjax' as a value.ts(2708)
```

How to fix it?